# Bootstrap modal forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing an error in bootstrap modals forms where the forms is displaying properly after i click on the button but that area will where the form is displaying is getting blocked ! Its very hard to explain you can find the link here where i am facing an issue [Link here](http://seofaceup.com/demo4/index.php)

Now when you click Quick Enquiry the pop up will be visible but refresh the page and go to service and other navigation links the area is getting blocked!!

Here is my code

```css
#modal_contact input[type="text"]{
 width: 320px;
 max-width: 100%;
 padding: 16px 10px;
 border: 1px solid #828fac;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -o-border-radius: 5px;
 color: #b6b7b8;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: helvetica;
 box-shadow: none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 -o-box-shadow: none;
 margin-left: 80px;
}

#modal_contact input[type="submit"]{
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 background: #8248ac;
 padding: 20px 13px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -o-border-radius: 5px;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<li>
            <div id="pks"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="text-decoration:none">QUICK ENQUIRY</a></div>
           </li>
                  
                  

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h1 class="modal-title"><br><font size="6" color="#8348ac"><center>Have A Questions?</center></font><br></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form id="modal_contact">
        Full Name  : <input type="text" name="name" class="name" placeholder="Full Name"><br>
        Email Id :&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="email" class="email" placeholder="Email address"><br>
        Phone No : <input type="text" name="phone" class="email" placeholder="Phone no"><br>
        Website : &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="website" class="email" placeholder="Your Website"><br>
         Questions : <input type="text" name="question" class="email" placeholder="Your Question??">
        <center><input type="submit" name="questions"  value="Send Message"></center>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Is it just me or does the modal `div` not exist on the services page.

Comment: Modal code is only available in index page.

Comment: Modal code is only there in index page

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
```

This should be hidden by default.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="display:none;">
```